# Using python, how do I select a random row from a .csv file which has 7 columns and take the data as input to 3 different field through selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner to selenium-python and I am trying to fetch 3 specific column data from a randow row in a csv file with 7 columns and using it as input to 3 different fields for my website in selenium. I have 2 issues with the above scenario:
1- I am only able to complete the above scenario if I delete 4 columns from the csv file manually.
2- Even after the manual edit, sometimes the columns can have null values and I face the timeout exception error, in that case how do I avoid the timeout exception error?

```
def add_type(self):
    data = [r for r in csv.reader(open('myfile.csv'))]
    test_data = random.choice(data)
    data_dict = {'type_1': test_data[0], 'type_2': test_data[1], 'type_3': test_data[2]}
    type_1, type_2, type_3 = data_dict.values()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.type_1_dropdown_xpath))).send_keys(type_1)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.type_2_dropdown_xpath))).send_keys(type_2)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.type_3_dropdown_xpath))).send_keys(type_3)
```

The above code gets the job partially done, but now I'm not sure how to fetch the row values randomly and pass it to the relevant fields without manually editing the file and avoiding the error for possible null values.
Thanks for any help in advance and apologies for any inconvenience in explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reading only specific columns from the CSV file: You can modify your code to read only the first three columns of each row by using list slicing.

```py
import csv
import random
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def add_type(self):
    # Read only specific columns (first three columns) from the CSV file
    data = [r[:3] for r in csv.reader(open('myfile.csv'))]
    
    # Choose a random row from the data
    test_data = random.choice(data)
    
    # Extract values from the selected row
    type_1, type_2, type_3 = test_data
    
    # Check for null values and handle them
    if None in (type_1, type_2, type_3):
        # Handle the case of null values here
        print("Null value detected in the selected row.")
        return
    
    # Send the values to the relevant fields on the website
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.type_1_dropdown_xpath))).send_keys(type_1)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.type_2_dropdown_xpath))).send_keys(type_2)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.type_3_dropdown_xpath))).send_keys(type_3)
```

In this modified code we used list slicing (`r[:3]`) to read only the first three columns of each row from the CSV file.